# C++: Assigning values to pointer members

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following code:

```
template<class T>
class RandomTreeNode {
private:
    RandomTreeNode<T> *left;
    RandomTreeNode<T> *right;
public:
    RandomTreeNode(): left(0), right(0) {}

    void create_left_child(){ left = &RandomTreeNode<T>();}
    void create_right_child(){ right = &RandomTreeNode<T>();}
```

But this gives me a compile error because I am pointing to the address of a temporary variable. I don't want the new RandomTreeNode's being created to be destroyed at the end of the function, how can I achieve this?

Comment: If you `new` them, then, unlike temporaries, they will not be destroyed at the end of the function. So what is the question, again?

Comment: It's good to see you decided to follow my [advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015708/c-incomplete-type#comment17663775_13015755) from your last question! /sarcasm

Comment: @Praetorian why would he? /sarcasm :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
void create_left_child()
{
    left = new RandomTreeNode<T>();
}

void create_right_child()
{
    right = new RandomTreeNode<T>();
}
```

And remember you have to delete them when you no longer need them (probably when the entire tree is destructed, or when that particular node gets deleted).

Comment: Thanks, I will accept once SO lets me (have to wait a certain amount of time)

Comment: Absolutely correct. Of course, now there will be corresponding `delete` calls as well.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
template<class T>
class RandomTreeNode {
    std::unique_ptr<RandomTreeNode<T> > left;
    std::unique_ptr<RandomTreeNode<T> > right;

    RandomTreeNode(): left(0), right(0) {}

    void create_left_child(){ left.reset(new RandomTreeNode<T>());}
    void create_right_child(){ right.reset(new RandomTreeNode<T>());}
}
```

There'd be no need for a destructor and no manual memory management.